# Gson won't convert automatically generated class from GSON plugin

Tags: android, gson

I have the following .json file -

```
   {
      "IDs":[
         "1716136233",
         "2030187302",
         "2048978077",
         "2366739744",
         "2893154331",
         "2933460506",
         "3103364330",
         "3156078714",
         "3246372427",
         "3917238269",
         "4120130712",
         "4219976332",
         "4291368197",
         "7157045144",
         "97qIzbJhgPVeyPtMFIpbvtBjdz72",
         "AhfGRayljDMx2G3UbEnxCFSjzV03",
         "hEej5AN4DpYXR0kOklIAs9sUxwX2",
         "5805506365",
         "12915030523",
         "AAcKGIJUYEYm9bzEmKfXSDK17Xf2",
         "xVCKjchpAzXNbd4NNrEJgN50Ap42",
         "E47aII272cVDI9m3fsT45V3XdP03",
         "yqvCupYxHUVWVK2jmkAVvPcAXvr1",
         "uFWidwQk0INUVdjXDSFZNjjHGrm2",
         "1eHERZ2WiJTNTPF7y6RVDZFf65n1",
         "Z4BzSFk5OpQK0VxPThyIfksOESv1",
         "pNfP2xUCxbfslMTQeSU6Ifxr1rV2",
         "ka2GdJ2cmRYHRgp8xyDqDRkZ9ys1",
         "cAWsikLAj3XMsIaSpHzjc0ixlFV2",
         "MzILthuDV9aWlvxqAAByMzfTUqK2",
         "6617291130",
         "RTzEt5DpBPTmQqzgOXXq2IGvoKL2",
         "nz9py8DslHNbLgduvxCfLVOLoMg1",
         "1Fici0ZStbXAccLKs5dh72xI0ZV2",
         "13694871353",
         "pyOB3Bhy4AaZ5GPUW4WLLmyD1Jd2",
         "NvcjLcHwfCTjTbjVOjfafukPNp32",
         "TSiTVkNY7qcFY9QxZ7r4CzKckLn1",
         "4329923139",
         "FgytkHqf0GddRqTyoguTh0aoxyG2",
         "2uXKy54kvyY1cvCD9ut5CvzyCGY2",
         "W4C3ueCQ0QYKNO8UDys4gt0RmNW2",
         "ixU5ro9ZeldRVy0Q5vTJ5HSGHyB2",
         "7308184033",
         "Mnox4kviNhPWiZwQU3U3oi39DTf2",
         "gxUIfqN9AFe5GY7Aj42pdlsbAk62",
         "wuWZdHyqzBUOElbv6c5Pp4GGwwE2",
         "1IwatVMcZKW30u9Ec6ofujhfqDQ2",
         "Or014Dw6gTPTisolKfTsb0pxblh2",
         "lbKFCsNTaKPFqkXG0gbogw6U5IQ2",
         "DqbG3g4DdlQbhbzIZoWlyFkqsJF3",
         "CEOMlUdMm2Q0FrqHlUBcWosLJt43",
         "bPmSONjHNBcUIDgrPZZzrsOcP7N2",
         "pp6ejp11AferP1zWbnKRcUXYqPm1",
         "En4oViJj0keGl9SoKzCW4FRi8zc2",
         "LwlmJ1wBXGdzBFmed7Np9AFQTkh1",
         "TcqhUChpfGSgVGg4jGoEcbXMUwP2",
         "4552B86LWQPCtekybJBd97dOP033",
         "WV5PytXFFBgQzVnE3Ar9TjFzbuj2",
         "Fh7ahcUJatNs0KLyUaOA7KYPekt1",
         "DHmEB44BDrRl706AqmmYBUORWwB3",
         "TKmfA6DfiZXApsCtVcu6LMIFZ7A3",
         "yLT1HUat2ZPC4UfqGOI4edRjjgw1",
         "DC3qrMXZa0Rs66WfyA3RCJIJqlo1",
         "sznynbcWiMbVwADCfhvluRfyyX12",
         "uWccGs4mkrRtuxsPt5D9Rmvhlzo2",
         "kD6If8EeS2flhCBNAkJaN9QfSNr2",
      ]
   }
```

I have created the following class using the GsonFormatter plugin for android studio, pasting the following .json code -

```
public class ID {


  private List<String> IDs;

  public List<String> getIDs() {
    return IDs;
  }

  public void setIDs(List<String> IDs) {
    this.IDs = IDs;
  }
}
```

but for some reason when trying to using the Gson method fromJson(response, ID.class) I am getting null and not the type that was auto generated for me -

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
    ID id = gson.fromJson(response, ID.class);
    Log.d("id - ", id.toString());
```

It prints to the log "id - null"

Why?

Comment: I think it is because your data in not of proper json type. If you see Ids is list but not of key and value. There is no key.

Comment: Make your `private List<String> IDs;` variable public to make it serialized. Gson can't serialize private variables.

Comment: `"kD6If8EeS2flhCBNAkJaN9QfSNr2",]` depending on how lenient the parser is, this part may break because it ends with a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code it works, translate it into java:

```
   data class Data(@SerializedName("IDs") val iDs: List<String>) {

        companion object {
            fun fromJson(json: String): Data {
                val data = Gson().fromJson(json, Data::class.java)

                return data
            }
        }

    }
```

Using:

```
val data = Data.fromJson(jsonString)
```